# Javascript: Trying to change the input src in a specific screen width

Tags: javascript, input, width, media-queries, src

Lets imagine I have this code:

```
<script>
        if (screen.width > 1008) {
            alert("A");
        }
        else{
            alert("B");
        }
</script>
```

It actually prints A if I load it at a screen of more than 1008px of width. But if I do this:

```
<script>
            if (screen.width > 1008) {
                document.querySelector('#inputDicionario').src = "other_image.png";
                alert("A");
            }
            else{
                alert("B");
            }
    </script>
```

So that `inputDicionario` refers to the following input:

```
<input class="botaoDicionario" type="image" src="icone_dicionario.jpg" value="" id="inputDicionario">
```

it results in nothing. The alerts doesn't appear, and the `src` of the `input` is not exchanged to another image. Why?

EDIT:If I use `inputDicionario`s class instead of it`s ID, it works.

EDIT 2:At the console, appears the following errors:

```
CLAWS.html:10 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null
CLAWS.html:87 Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

At line 10, the input is defined. At line 87, there is the script.

EDIT 3: It`s magically working now. But I keep without understanding what happened.

Comment: Well there must be a bug then. I think: `cannot access the property src of undefined`. Where in your page is the script block? For this to work the script block needs to be after the `img`.

Comment: It is . It`s before the end of the page.

Comment: Then I root for Avitus option.

Comment: What's document.getElementById('inputDicionario')? Try in the console

Comment: it appears "<input class="botaoDicionario" type="image" src="icone_dicionario.jpg" value="" id="inputDicionario">". So, it`s pointing correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The reason nothing probably happens is the query selector only works on more modern type browsers.
You can see supported browsers at: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

I recommend you change your script to be:

```
<script>
            if (screen.width > 1008) {
                document.getElementById('inputDicionario').src = "other_image.png";
                alert("A");
            }
            else{
                alert("B");
            }
    </script>
```